# How to detect dead or unused code in Angular?

Tags: angular, typescript, refactoring, automated-refactoring

I and my team are working on an **angular** application from more than a year now. As part of our code refactoring process we want to **delete unused or dead code** from our repo.

Is there any **technique or tool** which automatically detects this unused code from our repo, the it would be helpful for us to it instead of wasting a lot of time and efforts detecting them manually?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Detect unused methods - Visual Studio Code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62551931/detect-unused-methods-visual-studio-code)

Answer (score 4):

[WebStorm](https://www.jetbrains.com/webstorm/) can find dead code.

In the menu bar select `Code > Inspect Code...`:

[image]

In the report that it generates, drill down into `JavaScript and Typscript > Unused symbols`:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

For VS Code you can use this: https://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-unused-vars
`What it does`: Variables that are declared and not used anywhere in the code are most likely an error due to incomplete refactoring. Such variables take up space in the code and can lead to confusion by readers.

There isn't something that delete the code for you, but I think this is a good extension to start with.

If you use sublime there is nothing since is just a text editor

Comment: Thanks Jacopo But I already used this VS Code extension throughout our development. What I want to detect is any uncalled methods, never rendered html templates or never used css classes.

Comment: I am using 'Jetbrains Webstorm' to resolve mentioned issues. Download link: https://www.jetbrains.com/webstorm/download/

Comment: Is there an equivalent Extension for VS Code?

Comment: This isn't really a VS Code thing but just an eslint rule that you can set for projects that's agnostic to what IDE you're using.

Answer (score 1):

Thats very simple. if you run your application with `" ng serve --aot "` cli command instead of `" ng serve "` , it shows you a hole number of these dead codes(like when you leave `" ng build --prod "` command).

Comment: Note: The `--aot` flag is not in the latest Angular CLI, and it is not mentioned in the documentation. 
https://angular.io/cli/serve