# Detect unused methods - Visual Studio Code

Tags: angular, typescript, visual-studio-code

Is there a way to detect unused methods in a typescript file (Angular) in Visual Studio Code?
I've tried a couple of plugins for Angular but in vain.
Web Storm used to grey out the unused methods by default. Looking for a similar thing in VS Code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is currently not possible to detect unused public methods in VSCode (you can check for updates [here](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/29293)). However, if it's a private method, you can mark it as private and VSCode is able to look for whether it is used or not within the scope (although do remember: methods used in the HTML template are public).

If the public method checks are important for you, you'll have to either wait, or contribute to the VSCode community. I still use VSCode but if it is a necessity for you, just switch to WebStorm for the moment.

Answer (score 2):

Hi You can try to run your application with `" ng serve --aot "` cli command instead of `" ng serve "` , it shows you a whole number of these unused codes(like when you leave `" ng build --prod "` command).

Or you can try this method but I'm not shure of this :

https://alexjover.com/blog/tree-shaking-with-webpack-2-typescript-and-babel/

Hope it will work!